# Obtener texto entrada tkinter

Tags: python, post, tkinter, get

Quiero que el texto que yo introduzca en la entrada de la ventana, luego de hacer click en start me lo devuelva en esta variable:

```
 d = (Inventory_data.get ("Inventory_data")). get ("texto introducido")
```

Codigo:

```
ventana = Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x300+100+100")
ventana.title("MijaGato")
Tag_Name = Label(text="Name Of Tag").place(x=200, y=100)
entrada = StringVar()
textUsuario = Entry(ventana,textvariable=entrada,width=30).place(x=150, y=140)
button = Button(ventana, text="Start").place(x=220, y=180)
ventana.mainloop
```

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar el argumento `command` de tu`tkinter.Button` para pasarle una función que sea ejecutada cuando sea pulsado.

Antes unas cuantas observaciones

- Los imports de la forma `from modulo imports*` son una mala practica y deben evitarse excepto en casos muy concretos. Entre las razones esta que dificulta la legibilidad del código, puebla el espacio de nombres actual sin razón y propicia la colisión entre imports o entre los identificadores propios del modulo. Recordar dos máximas del zen de Python, "Explicito mejor que implícito" y "La legibilidad cuenta".
- Cuando aplicas el método `place` (o `pack`, `grid`, etc) sobre una instancia de un Widget se retorna `None`. Cuando haces:

  ```
  textUsuario = Entry(...).place(...)
  ```

  Tu variable `textUsuario` no hace referencia a un `Entry` sino que contiene `None`. Si necesitas usar en algún momento esta variable para acceder al widget en un futuro debes aplicar el método en otra linea:

  ```
  textUsuario = Entry(...)
  textUsuario.place(...)
  ```

  En caso contrario no tiene sentido usar la variable, simplemente crea el widget con:

  ```
  Entry(...).place(...)
  ```
- Por último, no estas llamando al método `mainloop`. Si te funciona el código es porque lo ejecutas en el IDLE posiblemente (está creado en Tkinter y tiene su propio `mainloop`). Debe ser:

  ```
  ventana.mainloop()
  #               ^^
  ```

Bien como comente al principio, solo necesitas crear una función que sea llamada cuando pulsas el botón:

```
import tkinter as tk


def consulta():
    d = (Inventory_data.get ("Inventory_data")). get (entrada.get())
    # Resto del código

ventana = tk.Tk()
ventana.geometry("500x300+100+100")
ventana.title("MijaGato")

tk.Label(ventana, text="Name Of Tag").place(x=200, y=100)
entrada = tk.StringVar()
tk.Entry(ventana, textvariable=entrada, width=30).place(x=150, y=140)
tk.Button(ventana, text="Start",  command = consulta).place(x=220, y=180)
ventana.mainloop()
```

Se usa el método `get` para obtener el valor de la `stringVar`. Como es obvio, el diccionario `Inventory_data` debe ser una variable global para que pueda ser accedida desde la función `consulta`.

> **Nota:** En caso de usar Python 2.x solo cambiar el import por `import Tkinter as tk`.

---

> **Aviso:** La función llamada por el botón debe retornar en un tiempo corto. Es una llamada bloqueante, si tarda en retornar el `mainloop` no puede actualizar la GUI ni responder a eventos por lo que la aplicación se congelará y dejará de responder. Si se pretende lanzar una operación que tarda en ejecutarse se debe implementar algún tipo de concurrencia (hilos, procesos, corrutinas, etc) de forma que el hilo principal no se bloquee en ningún momento.